# Maintain Oracle lock on Transactional Java method after truncate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, transactions, ejb

I got a transactional method in Java annotated with: @Transactional(javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)

Lets assume we have the following method:

```
@Transactional(javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void testLock()  {
    lockTables();
    truncateTables();
    ...
}
```

**lockTables()** does a DB lock on the tables, which works fine. Once the application executes the **truncateTables()** method, which does execute a Truncate statement, the lock is released. I am aware that truncate is a DDL statement and on Oracle it performs also a commit, thus releasing the lock as well.

Is there a way to maintain somehow the lock also after a truncate statement? Relocking the table after the truncate is not the best solution i can think of.

Note: I am running on an oracle DB.

Comment: Maybe run the truncate in a nested transaction?

Comment: @The Impaler , could you provide an example or some further details please.

Comment: I haven't tested it recently, but the steps could be: 1) Place the `truncateTables()` method in a **different bean** so the call is intercepted by Spring (not just separate method). 2) Add the `REQUIRES_NEW` annotation to the latter; the main method `testLock()` doesn't need `REQUIRES_NEW`; any normal transaction will do.